# Golang параллельное распределение

Tags: golang

Как параллельно распределить функции вызова http запросов?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

)




func foo() {

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        b, err := http.Get("http://golang.org")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error")
        } else {
            fmt.Println(b.Header)
            fmt.Println(b.StatusCode)
        }
    }

} 

func foo1() {

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        b, err := http.Get("http://golang.org")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error")
        } else {
            fmt.Println(b.Header)
            fmt.Println(b.StatusCode)
        }
    }

} 
func foo2() {

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        b, err := http.Get("http://golang.org")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error")
        } else {
            fmt.Println(b.Header)
            fmt.Println(b.StatusCode)
        }
    }

} 

func main() {
    foo();
    foo1();
    foo2();
    fmt.Println("Ok")
}
```

Выполняется все медленно и поочередно. Пробовал через горутины go foo1() ; go foo2() тоже не работает. Что делать?

Comment: Запустить их в горутинах: go функция()

Comment: @tilin забыл дописать* пробовал уже и через go foo1(); go foo2(); тоже не работает

Comment: У вас в каждой функции по 10 запросов идет последовательно, и они никак не будут параллельны.

Comment: @tilin эм... а как сделать многопоточно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func foo() {
    b, err := http.Get("http://golang.org")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(b.Header)
        fmt.Println(b.StatusCode)
    }
} 

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go foo()
    }

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)

    fmt.Println("Ok")
}
```

Comment: О! Вот теперь то что доктор прописал! Спасибо большое